# Custom html page on Android Lockscreen

Tags: android, html, widget

How to set some html page as always displaying (and interactive) on lockscreen of my Android Tablet?

I am looking for app where I configure just desired URI and all rest of work I do on my own with html+css+javascript without any need to compile custom apk's.

(So I could craft some custom news/wather/whatever content conenientely)